# Using query strings inside of a EPUB3 file

Tags: javascript, query-string, epub, epub3

I am producing a EPUB3 ebook containing 140 (short) videos. There is a index-file with hyperlinks to a separate `showVideo.html` file that has a HTML5 video element. My idea was to submit each video filename via query string to the `showVideo.html` which reads the query string via javascript and puts the value into the video element.

Index file link:

```
<a href="showVideo.html?unit=E1">Click to watch E1</a>
```

This does indeed work if I write the following code into the `manifest` of my `content.opf` file:

```
<item id="vid_player" href="showVideo.html?unit=E1"
 media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
```

But if I do it that way, I have to add 140 items to the manifest. Just excluding the query string in the manifest does *not* work:

```
<item id="vid_player" href="showVideo.html" 
 media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
```

Do you guys possibly have a solution? Query string method was just my idea, maybe there's a better technique.

Thank you

Marvin

Comment: You say "it doesn't work"--how doesn't it work? `epubcheck` error? Doesn't work on what e-reading platform? Also, is there some reason you're not adding the `properties='scripted'` attribute to the `<item>` element?

Comment: I am sorry torazaburo, I forgot to describe. It is not working on Readium which is our reference reading system. Clicking on the hyperlink fails if the content-file was not in the `manifest`. The `scripted`was new to me, but I will use it from now on :-). Thank you.

Comment: I'm a little surprised at Readium's behavior. Anyway, I suspect it would work if you built the href at load time (e.g.,  `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("a"),function(a){a.setAttribute("href"), "showVideo.html+"?"+a.dataset.videoName);});`). But Liza's solution sounds ideal.

Comment: Unfortunately Liza's solution does not work in EPUB, so I want to try that Array thing, but I am not familiar with it. I presume the `dataset.videoName` has to be declared before (how?) and is this code built inside a function that will be called in every `a` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid `epubcheck`'s overly fastidious checking, you can do the following.

1. Add a `data-video` attribute to the `<a>` element, as in `<a data-video='E1'>`.
2. Add an event listener to the `click` event on the relevant `<a>` elements.
3. Within the event handler, set `location.href` to `"showRef.html?Unit=" + elt.dataset.video` or the equivalent.
4. Within `showRef.html`, parse the query string and do the right thing.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that. The JS code is: `var el = document.getElementById("a_E1");` and `el.addEventListener("click", function() {el.href = "showVideo.html?unit=" + el.dataset.video;}, false);`. No problems at all in pure Chrome, but no chance in Readium. There is no reaction on click, as if the reference is missing in `manifest`. ...

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant, inside the click handler, explicitly set `window.location.href`. I do this myself (actually using `#id` fragments instead of query strings, and it works fine in Readium.

Comment: Also, make sure to set `evt.preventDefault()` from within handler.

Comment: That is my code now and it does what it is supposed to ;-) `<a href="dummy.html" data-video="E1" onclick="window.location.href='showVideo.html?unit=' + this.dataset.video; return false; this.preventDefault();">`. Thank you very much Mr Myers!

Comment: Nice answer! I don't know why using @data-* hadn't occurred to me!

Comment: Something stupid: epubcheck found an error because the `dummy.html` (of course) doesn't exist. I changed the `href` from `dummy.html` to `showVideo.html` for not linking to a missing file, BUT: now it takes my directly to `showVideo.html` without following the `onclick`-function. Maybe the `preventDefault()` is not working? My latest code is: `<a href="showVideo.html" onclick="event.preventDefault(); window.location.href='showVideo.html?unit=' + this.dataset.video;" data-video="E1">`.

Comment: Try using `href="#"`.

Comment: Also note that there's no particular reason this has to be an `<a>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using JS to parse the ID of the video anyway, try using a fragment identifier instead of a query param: `<a href="showVideo.html#E1">` You won't get a validation error that way, and you can retrieve the value in JS as `location.hash`.

Comment: Thanks Liza, I tried that outside of an epub container and it worked like a charm. Awesome. But inside of the container, I only get it working when in `showVideo.html` there's an element with the ìd` called "E1" (besides the other 139 video files). Otherwise: `'E1': fragment identifier is not defined in 'OPS/showVideo.html'` = clicking the hyperlink makes a white page.

Comment: That's frustrating. Epubcheck trying to be helpful because it thinks you've forgotten a link, but of course it doesn't understand your goal. I had forgotten it would also complain about fragids. Unfortunately I think your best bet is Alberto Pettarin's approach above, even though I agree it's silly to have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use JavaScript for that, try what Liza Daly suggested --- bearing in mind that your EPUB 3 eBook will probably work now only on iBooks (maybe Readium and Kobo app).

If your only purpose is to "select" the video, why don't you simply generate one XHTML page for each video and point your links from the playlist to them? 140 is not a big "number" of elements to be added to the manifest, after all.

Alternatively, you can create a single XHTML page, say `videoplayer.xhtml`, using `div`s (with associated CSS properties `page-break-after` , `page-break-before`) like this:

```
<div class="videoplayer" id="video001">
 <video src="video001.mp4" ... />
</div>
<div class="videoplayer" id="video002">
 <video src="video002.mp4" ... />
</div>
...
<div class="videoplayer" id="video140">
 <video src="video140.mp4" ... />
</div>
```

so that your playlist will link to `videoplayer.xhtml#video001`, etc. Not using JavaScript, you have better chances it will work on multiple devices.

Comment: Having one xhtml page with all videos and using the page-break property is a good idea, however this results in a Oh, Snap Chrome error (too many videos in one file makes the browser fail - I tried embedding all videos on my previously mentioned index file). Sure I could use, let's say, like 3 xhtml documents which does not result in this error.